# iOS6 screen rotation by code

Tags: ios, screen-rotation

I have a problem with this code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
```

It works well in one of my projects, but not in another. I've used the same code in both projects. The only difference is that in the first project (where it works), there is only a view controller, while in the second project there is also a navigation controller. I'm sure that's the problem, but I don't know why...

I'm spending many, many hours to resolve this 'rotation issue' and I'm so tired!

Comment: :))
you have right... but believe me, I'm going crazy for this issue

Comment: @timjver: thanks... An italian @ console!!